# Webdriver Phantomjs and Angular $window.outerWidth not working

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm building an application with angularjs and am end-to-end testing it with Webdriver using the PhantomJS Driver.
The app must support different screen sizes and also has some shortcuts integrated to display a sidebar.

Is use the following function to determine if I must show the sidebar. In chrome and firefox all works well but when I run the code in my end tot end tests with PhantomJS, this returns false.

```
function isScreenWithSizeBiggerThan(screenSize) {
    return $window.outerWidth > screenSize;
}
```

I tried setting the screen size but to no avail. Anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dimension size = remoteWebDriver.manage().window().getSize();
remoteWebDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
Dimension size2 = remoteWebDriver.manage().window().getSize();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) remoteWebDriver;
js.executeScript("window.outerWidth=1920");
js.executeScript("window.outerHeight=1080");
```

Thanks in advance!